# Pls Help! My transactions on multibit HD is yet to be confirmed after 24hrs

Tags: blockchain, multibit, unconfirmed-transactions

please can anyone help here as I'm a beginner on btc.
I sent some bitcoins but after more than 24 hours is not yet confirmed but shows it has been seen by peers on multibit HD. I have tried on 5 occasions on repair wallet but yet no results.

https://blockchain.info/tx/b57acae08aa1aaff70d8c74bf823e6a5b6f536b1524cc777d9f4e89794ca64bc

3b1b1c3822ab74cad22ca34731cb298d906e04acc741bb5e7fc38b2b333c2ccc

b03eb0087f4c75d4bdfa2e1788a92b1402037f210f17caf71b6a66d73597356c

I decided to transfer my other wallet to a new wallet and still not showing too.

https://blockchain.info/tx/c7309ba1267012506fcb99de79f060935811fc74e049df6e22388b874903192a

Thanks

N.B: fess was set as default, been over 36 hours and the transaction not reflecting on the receiving wallet

Comment: Always check [the current backlog](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions) when this happens. The network is experiencing exceptional circumstances. We just need to wait.

Comment: I didnt know about this. just started using multibit HD. I'm getting a bit worried that I have lost my money :(

Comment: @jenny Your money isn't lost - the nodes on the network disagree about who owns it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nick. But please any suggestion of how I can recover it? Thanks